# Where is push source found and how to compile it in direct show

Tags: windows, directshow

I have installed the windows SDK, and was wondering where and how I can find and compile the push source filters as I'm trying to make a screen recording software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Windows SDK 7.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279), with samples
- \Samples\multimedia\directshow\filters\pushsource
- supplementary MSDN information: [Push Source Filters Sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377481)

Building sample is straightforward (using supplied solution/project file) with the only trick that you might need to build BaseClasses project with the same configuration/options first:

- [How to compile directshow sample filter (pushsource) at VS 2005?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/52c3a6d8-9f11-4539-af4a-707e72bb4ee5/how-to-compile-directshow-sample-filter-pushsource-at-vs-2005?forum=windowsdirectshowdevelopment)
- [Linking SDK samples - Microsoft Visual Studio 2008](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/3e41ae8f-36ea-4661-a285-30a931e5279b/linking-sdk-samples-microsoft-visual-studio-2008?forum=windowsdirectshowdevelopment)

Comment: ah yah, forgot to add that, i'm on windows 10, windows sdk 7.1 didn't work.

Comment: It makes it more difficult but it can work if you try hard enough. Virtual system or perhaps compatibility mode, or download as ISO with finding CAB of your interest with the files. The samples are no longer provided with SDK 8.0+. Or maybe you can find that online, someone's copy from public repository ([example](https://github.com/hbuexinxin/Windows7-sdk-samples/tree/master/Samples/multimedia/directshow/filters/pushsource)).

Comment: hey, i found a different installer for windows sdk 7.0 on microsoft, but now i dont know how i would go about compiling the samples.

Comment: See above - just upgrade the projects to VS version you use and build BaseClasses then PushSource.

Comment: i did that, i succesfully built baseclasses but push source failed with 82 errors.